How to search a table on a phrase that I pass through a ternary operator
I am using the gridJS table to show the data that I retrieve from the DB.
When I use the table search if I go to search for the names of the data (so by name experience) that I get from the DB I have no problem, while if I search for "no experience" (a phrase that I pass through a ternary operator if the data does not exist in the DB) I get
"No data found".
This is the code that I use to show the data in the specific column:
{
  name: 'Experiences',
  formatter: (experiences) => gridjs.html(`<b style="vertical-align:middle;"><ul class="ps-1 mt-3"> ${experiences.length > 0 ? experiences.map(experience => `<li><a title="Experience information" href='/experience/show/${experience.id}'>${experience.name}</a></li>`).join('') : "<span class='p-0 mt-3'><u style='color:red'>no experience </u></span></ul></b>"}`)
},

This instead, is the configuration of the table, in particular it shows how I retrieve the data
equal to 2):
server: {
  url: '/place/data',
  then: data => data.map((place, i) => [i + 1, place.name, place.experiences, place.creator, place.description])
         },
  search: {
           selector: (cell, rowIndex, cellIndex) => cellIndex === 2 ? cell.map(el => el.name) : cell
          },
  }).render(document.getElementById("table"));

Can you help me please?
